# Navbar Disappears Bug

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to make an item on my nav menu hide when the section is hidden. Right now, I'm using jQuery to move and hide the section and media queries to hide and display the nav menu items. I am not using a html/css framework for the nav bar. This is the related nav section in my HTML:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li class="music-link"><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tour">Tour</a></li>
   <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    div .music-link {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

My current issue is a little difficult to explain, so please let me know if this is not clear. My navbar completely hides when it is resized after I have opened and closed the mobile version of the navbar. This is what I do...

1. refresh the page at full screen
2. resize the screen to width < 767px
   open
3. the mobile nav manu (hamburger icon)
4. close the mobile nav menu
5. resize to larger screen

After 5 is completed, there is no nav menu at all. It's just blank. Any ideas on what is happening? If you need more code, please let me know. There's a good amount, so I'm trying to limit it to what I think is relevant and I'm somewhat new to this forum. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

EDIT: Here is the rest of my relevant code to this issue...

nav css:

```
/* Main Nav */
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 6px 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #248dd1;
}

/* Mobile Nav */
.mobile-nav-icon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-icon i {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Sticy Nav */
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #efefef;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.sticky .main-nav { margin-top: 10px }

.sticky .main-nav li a:link,
.sticky .main-nav li a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 0;
    color: #248dd1;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.sticky .main-nav li a:hover,
.sticky .main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #248dd1;
}

.sticky .logo { display: none; }
.sticky .logo-black { display: block; }
```

Media Queries for Nav:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    .mobile-nav-icon { display: inline-block; }

    .main-nav { 
        float: left;
        margin: 35px 15px 0 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .main-nav li { display: block; }

    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .sticky .main-nav { margin-top: 10px }

    .sticky .main-nav li a:link,
    .sticky .main-nav li a:visited { padding: 10px 0; }
    .sticky .mobile-nav-icon { margin-top: 10px; }
    .sticky .mobile-nav-icon i { color: #555; }
    div .music-link { display: none; }
}
```

And this is my jQuery related to the nav bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $pane = $('#pane1');

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize < 647) {
            //if the window is greater than 647px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $(".section-music").each(function() {
                $(this).detach().insertAfter("body").css("display", "none");
            });
            $.scrollify.update();
        }
        if (windowsize >= 647) {
            //if the window is greater than 647px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $(".section-music").detach().insertAfter(".section-about").css("display", "block");
            $.scrollify.update();
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);


    // MOBILE NAVIGATION
    $(".mobile-nav-icon").click(function() {
        var nav = $(".main-nav");
        var icon = $(".mobile-nav-icon i");

        nav.slideToggle(200);
        if(icon.hasClass("ion-navicon-round")) {
            icon.addClass("ion-close-round");
            icon.removeClass("ion-navicon-round");
        } else {
            icon.addClass("ion-navicon-round");
            icon.removeClass("ion-close-round");
        }
    });
});
```

There is a bit more, but it only detects if the page is being viewed on certain kinds of phones or in Internet Explorer, as some parts of my website don't work on IE...

It's also worthwhile to add, if I open the mobile navigation on a small screen and don't close it, but then resize it to a larger screen, I can still see the full navigation for some reason. It's only when I close the mobile navigation that the normal nav disappears.

Thanks again!

Comment: Post enough that we can replicate the issue, but not the whole site or so much that we have to hunt for the relevant code. Read how to create a [mcve]. Also #3, I think you a word. I'm assuming whatever closes the menu in mobile applies `display: none;` and that's retained when you switch back to desktop.

Comment: I apologize, thank you for letting me know that wasn't enough. I have posted my relevant code to the new edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you resize the screen or when the media query is executed, it sets the display to none. But when you go back to the other screen size, there is not query to change the display back to block or whatever you're using. Write a query so that when the screen is resized to normal it sets display to something visible. I could be wrong but from the info you provided that seemed the most plausible.

Comment: I thought you might be right, but I tried setting both the main-nav or just the class itself back to visible, it stayed the same...I'm going to add more code to my original post. Hopefully, that will help a bit. Thanks for the reply!